# Does jGRASP support Java lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, jgrasp

I've worked in jGRASP for some time, and just started working with lambda expressions in Java. I can compile programs with lambda expressions, but when I try to run them I always get this error:

> No main methods, applets, or MIDlets found in file

Example program:

```
public class SquareComputer {

    interface IntegerMath {
        int operation(int a);   
    }

    public int operateUnary(int a, IntegerMath op) {
        return op.operation(a);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SquareComputer myApp = new SquareComputer();
        System.out.println(myApp.operateUnary(3, a -> a*a));
    }
}
```

If I comment out the last line, then the program compiles and runs as expected (doing nothing, of course).

Note that this program is a cut-down version of the Calculator example in the [Oracle tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). If I use the whole Calculator program, then the same thing happens: compiles but fails to find a main method to run; but comment out the lines using lambda expressions, and it runs fine. Likewise for the other program that I'm really working on; any single line compiled with a lambda expression causes the program to fail to find the main method.

Is this a problem with jGRASP, or my Java installation, or my understanding, or something else? And how can I resolve this?

**Edit:** A few more data points: If I have jGRASP display a UML diagram, the class with a lambda expression is uniquely marked as "External Class or Interface" (without the lambda expression, it is marked normally as "Project Class").

If I try to make a JAR file via jGRASP, with the regular expression, initially jGRASP cannot find the main-class; but once I specify it, the JAR class is made, and I can run it successfully, with the behavior I wanted, from outside jGRASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an out-of-date version of jGRASP (from 2013, before the introduction of lambda expressions to Java in 2014, I believe). Updating my installation of jGRASP to the current version cleared up my problems with finding the main-class when a lambda expression is compiled.

So: **Yes**, jGRASP does support lambda expressions currently (at least by version 2.0.1_09). But no, it did not prior to the appearance of lambda expressions in Java (sometime after version 2.0.0_03).